# CUDA FFT exception

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu, gpu

I'm trying to use CUDA FFT aka cufft library

Problem occurred when cufftPlan1d(..) throws an exception.

```
   #define NX 256
   #define BATCH 10

   cufftHandle plan;
   cufftComplex *data;
   cudaMalloc((void**)&data, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*BATCH);
   if (cudaGetLastError() != cudaSuccess){
         fprintf(stderr, "Cuda error: Failed to allocate\n");
         return;
   } 
   if (cufftPlan1d(&plan, NX, CUFFT_C2C, BATCH) != CUFFT_SUCCESS){
         fprintf(stderr, "CUFFT error: Plan creation failed");
         return;
   }
```

When the compiler hit the cufftPlan1d command, the output window on VS08 comes up with the following:

```
    first chance expection at 0x75af9617 in CudaFFTProject.exe Microsoft C++ exception: cufftResult_t at memory location 0x002df99c..
```

Comment: That isn't a compilation error, it is a runtime error. And your `cudaMalloc` call looks very odd. What is `sizeof(cudafftComplex*NX*BATCH)` supposed to mean? From your code and the spelling mistakes in the error message, it appears that what you are showing in the question isn't really what you are either running, or the error you are getting. Can you correct the question please?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown. If I just put a main() around it and compile it, it will run without any errors. So the problem is somewhere else in your code (like a buffer overflow or something). Can you edit the code into the *shortest possible* compilable example which exhibits the problem? Otherwise I fail to see how anyone can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from disorder in include files and linker input file (not sure which one of them).

My personal computer include cuda toolkit 4.2 and cuda toolkit 5 installation.

In VS08, Project properties:

Additional include:
use `"$(CUDA_PATH_V4_2)\include"`
instead of `$(CUDA_INC_PATH)`

Linker --> additional library directory -->
use `"(CUDA_PATH_V4_2)\lib\win32"`
instead of `$(CUDA_LIB_PATH)`