# cufftPlan2d exception

Tags: c++, cuda, fft

I am working with the cufft library.
I am using the *cufftPlan2d* function to create the plan I need.

```
cufftResult cuRes = cufftPlan2d(&m_fftPlanC2C, 1024, 1024, CUFFT_C2C);
```

And I'm getting this strange behavior, the call to *cufftPlan2d* throws an exception but is actually working fine, my *cufftHandle* is initialized and my following calls to *cufftExecC2C* give me the results I expect.

> First-chance exception at 0x000007FFFE9E811C in RTLab.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cufftResult_t at memory location 0x0000000000377C40.

However it is quite annoying to get this exception, so I would like to know if anyone had the same issue and found a solution or has some leads that could help. I'm using Cuda 5.0 with Visual Studio 2012.

I tried to run an example from the SDK, the convolutionFFT2D one (on VS2010) and it does the same (with the Debug>Exceptions>C++ Exceptions option checked).

Tell me if you need any further information.

Comment: Or right, I forgot to mention that, sorry ! 
I added it in the post.

Comment: Take a look to [this post] here on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545442/cuda-fft-exception), it may help.

Comment: The problem is somewhere else.. Could you show us the complete code..

Comment: [What is a First Chance Exception?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx): useful to know.

Comment: @SagarMasuti No I cannot show you my entire code unfortunately, too big project ^^.

Comment: However I looking into my include and lib directories, as mentioned in @Adriano 's link.

Comment: @beuleuppeup Which card are you using? Are you correctly setting the `compute` and `sm` compiler options?

Comment: I'm using a GTX 780, I've set these options to `compute_20,sm_20;compute_35,sm_35`

Comment: I'm gonna try writing a sample code that produces the same crash.

Comment: Well actually, the sample from the SDK (convolutionFFT2D) running on VS2010 produces the same exception ! I didn't see it earlier because I had nothing ticked in Debug>Exceptions toolbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first chance exception you report is an exception that is triggered *and caught properly* and handled inside the CUDA libraries.  It does not necessarily indicate a problem in your application.

If your application is running correctly, this issue can safely be ignored.  You won't see it if you run the application from the command line, only within visual studio.  As long as you do cuda and/or cufft error checking on your cufft API calls, and the api returns no errors, things should be OK.

You may also see this issue go away if you upgrade to CUDA 5.5